# Using silence package generates warning from silence.sty

Tags: beamer, errors, texmaker

the last warning shown in TexMaker, I cannot get rid of. Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[hyperref={unicode}]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Antibes} 
  \usecolortheme{dolphin} 
  \usefonttheme{professionalfonts} 
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
  % Numbered bibiolgraphy items
  \setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{\insertbiblabel}
} 



\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes,lmodern,silence}
\usepackage[style=numeric,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\WarningFilter{biblatex}{Patching footnotes failed}

% Remove small caps warning
\renewcommand\mkbibacro[1]{{\footnotesize\MakeUppercase{#1}}}

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}
% something
\end{document}
```

The strange warning produced.

```
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/silence/silence.sty
Package: silence 2012/07/02 v1.5b Selective filtering of warnings and error mes
sages
\sl@Save=\count162
\sl@StateNumber=\count163
\sl@MessageCount=\count164
\sl@Casualties=\count165
\sl@Filter=\toks46
\sl@Message=\toks47
\sl@UnexpandedMessage=\toks48
\sl@Mess@ge=\toks49
\sl@WarningCount=\count166
\sl@WarningNumber=\count167
\sl@WarningCasualties=\count168
\sl@TempBOW=\toks50
\sl@BankOfWarnings=\toks51
LaTeX Info: Redefining \GenericWarning on input line 433.
\sl@ErrorCount=\count169
\sl@ErrorNumber=\count170
\sl@ErrorCasualties=\count171
\sl@TempBOE=\toks52
\sl@BankOfErrors=\toks53
LaTeX Info: Redefining \GenericError on input line 601.
)
```

The warning cannot be silenced, as far as I my skills reach with silence package itself (because you would have to call the `\WarningsOff[silence]` before it is declared by `\usepackage{silence}` ).

My theory is, that it is not warning itself, it just picked up by TexMaker because it cointains `Warning` four times.

Anyone can tell if it is possible to get rid of it? Thank You!

Comment: Messages like `\sl@Save=\count161` are issued by the LaTeX kernel and are useful for debugging. There's no way of disabling them with `silence`; only changing the relevant kernel macros could do. Your conjecture seems good and this should be filed to Texmaker's developers.

Comment: I have used TexMaker's google code group for reporting some issues, but they never got any response. However, meanwhile, the issues I was reporting, got resolved - probably by fixes in new versions - I am not sure if I can track it down precisely. I am going to report this too.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue has been solved by a software updated (Texmaker), see OP's comments.

Comment: @egreg: Do you know which release of TexMaker has this bug fixed?